# Rails Array set to "0" after save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have built an array attribute into my model `@users`. I did this in the model user.rb `serialize :year, Array`.

I have a show page in my controller that first prints the `@user` and then changes the `@user.year`. It finishes by saving the `@user.year`.

The first time through when it prints `@user.year` it returns a `[]` to show that the array is empty. I print the array right before saving and it is populated with integers, but when I reload the next page the `@user.year` has switched from a `[]` to a `0`. Any idea why this is?

`:year` is an assessable attribute in the @user model.

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
p "print @user"
p @user
...
@user.today_steps = day['summary']['steps']
@user.year.unshift(@user.today_steps)
...
p @user.year
  if @user.save(validate: false)
    p "Updated"
  else 
    p "Failed to Update"
  end
end
end
```

The `@today_steps` does save and is shown in the next call, but `year` doesn't. Any idea why this is?

Comment: what datatype is year in your schema.rb

Comment: integer - but it should be serialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `serialize :year, Array` to work, the `year` attribute needs to be a string.

[Serialize](http://api.rubyonrails.org) stores the data in the database as yaml[1].

However, since your column type is integer, the yaml is being converted to an integer before being persisted to the database. Because of the way ruby converts strings to integers, 0 is the expected value given a yaml input.

```
y = [1,2,3].to_yaml # => "---\n- 1\n- 2\n- 3\n" 
y.to_i              # => 0
```

[1]: unless the class you specify implements load and dump

Comment: Wow, you fixed more bugs than you will ever know. Thanks also for the explanation on why it works this way